# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

hago una app en app inventor y la conecto a una base de datos de un host web.
pero al ver el codigo php del host web (BD) 
sale este error

conexion correcta
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in /storage/ssd5/808/13326808/public_html/datos.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: edad in /storage/ssd5/808/13326808/public_html/datos.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: ciudad in /storage/ssd5/808/13326808/public_html/datos.php on line 3

codigo:

```
include("conex.php");
$sql=$conex->query("Insert into `informacion` values(0,'".$_REQUEST["nombre"]."'.'".$_REQUEST['edad']."'.'".$_REQUEST['ciudad']."'");
/*if (!$sql){
    die('no se pudo conectar, error login');
}*/

$conex->close();
?>

y bueno, no inserto datos desde app inventor a la base de datos y creo que ese es mi error.
agradeceria la ayuda
```

Comment: como recibes esos datos por post o get???

Comment: los envío desde app inventor con la herramienta web poniendo el url del codigo anterior compilado

Answer (score 0):

intenta ver la variable con `var_dump()` de php para ver si están tus datos en ese *array*

```
include("conex.php");
$sql=$conex->query("Insert into `informacion` values(0,'".$_REQUEST["nombre"]."'.'".$_REQUEST['edad']."'.'".$_REQUEST['ciudad']."'");
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
/*if (!$sql){
    die('no se pudo conectar, error login');
}*/

$conex->close();
?>
```

tambien revisate con $_GET y $_POST, tener en cuenta tambien que estes enviando la peticion al servidor desde un cliente

Comment: (ya corregi algunos errores como en `informacion` va en realidad asi 'informacion' etc.) compile con el dump y me dice "array(0){}" que quiere decir?

Comment: @AldoPavon que esta vacio, revisate el $_GET Y el $_POST

Comment: @AldoPavon no necesariamente se supone que $_REQUEST puede acceder a variables de tipo $_GET, $_POST y $_COOKIE

Comment: Ya lo intenté, y aparece lo mismo, solo que el array(0){} ahora aparece 3 veces

Comment: @AldoPavon estas enviando la peticion desde un cliente? de lo contrario tendrias que ingresar las variables por metodo GET ejemplo: archivo.php?nombre=juan&edad=18&ciudad=quito

Comment: al llamar la URL

Comment: el problema es que no puedo definir esas variables como tal sino que debe ser lo que el cliente ingrese desde la app de app inventor